# Is it possible to detect mouse position in background program?

Tags: java, driver, device

Is it possible to detect mouse position by using background program while working on another program? I want stop background program if another program click stop button which is sticked on steady point. The another program is already maden program by apple. And Background program is java program.

Comment: You could try polling [`MouseInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/MouseInfo.html) on a regular bases

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Read up on AWT Robot.

Comment: Thank you! I got one question. Is it possible with fx? I already made program using Javafx.

Comment: I'm fairly sure FX doesn't have the functionality of AWT Robot, but it doesn't matter.  You can use AWT Robot inside an FX program, and it works just fine.